# Printer ignores duble printing side in Evince and Libreoffice, but respecting it in Okular

Tags: 18.04, printing, pdf, evince, duplex-printing

Our new printer (Toshiba e_STUDIO 3515) ignores the printing side, printing always on the long side, whatever selected in the printing dialogue.

Fine, but when I print two pages per sheet I prefer having the double printing on the shortest side..

Note also that while printed documents with Evince or Libreoffice have this problem, printing from Okular works fine, respecting the printing side.

Anything I can do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with manual selection of the printing drivers (the last within the list all with the same name "Toshiba e-STUDIO 3510c Series PS").